# Add and subtract from input field onkeyup vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, ref

I have a fixed number 100. When a user enters in numbers, I'd like these figures to be subtracted from the total of 100 but if deleted, the difference added back to the 100 total. This is what I have tried but it keeps subtracting without adding the difference back when I delete figures:

html:

```
                <input
                  type="number"
                  placeholder="Ex: 40"
                  v-model="e"
                  @keyup="validate()"
                  @blur="validate()"
                  required
                />
```

js:

```
const total = ref(100);
const e = ref("");

    const validate = (e) => {
            if(e.value){
        totalPercentages.value = total.value - e.value
      }
    };
```

Comment: Please explain your code as it seems incomplete and doesn't make any sense.  Why is the ref set to an empty string and why is there no ref attribute on the input?  Have you confirmed that the validate method works correctly with string properties?

Comment: You should not change the original value of 100 - if you change it you will not know what it was and won't be able to restore it when the other number is cleared. So, keep both values and use a computed value to track their difference.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion **:** Use `@blur()` to get the correct calculations.

Just to explain the logic, I created below code snippet with Vue version 2.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    e: null,
    total: 100
  },
  methods: {
    validate() {
      this.total = 100;
      if (!this.e) return;
      if (this.e <= this.total) {
        this.total = this.total - this.e;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input
         type="number"
         placeholder="Ex: 40"
         v-model="e"
         @blur="validate()"
         required
         />
         
   <span>Total : {{ total }}</span>      
</div>
```